# Any difference between String = null and String.isEmpty?

Tags: java, string, null

Is there any difference when using a if-statement to check if the string is empty by using String = null or String.isEmpty() ?

ie:

```
public String name;

if(name == null)
{
    //do something
}
```

or

```
public String name;

if(name.isEmpty())
{
    //do something
}
```

if there is any different (including performance issues) please let me know.

Comment: An empty string is not `null` but `isEmpty()`

Comment: They are not interchangeable as they don't do anything like each other so there is no point comparing their performance.  BTW: Why would you have a special method if it did the same thing as an operator?

Comment: in the second you will get NullPointerException

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The empty string is a string with zero length. The null value is not having a string at all.

- The expression `s == null` will return `false` if s is an empty string.
- The second version will throw a `NullPointerException` if the string is null.

Here's a table showing the differences:

```
+-------+-----------+----------------------+
| s     | s == null | s.isEmpty()          |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+
| null  | true      | NullPointerException |
| ""    | false     | true                 |
| "foo" | false     | false                |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: I love that table from @mark-byers and will add that as a .NET guy I miss stringvalue.IsNullOrEmpty() returning a boolean. So I added this to a helper class:
`public static Boolean IsNullOrEmpty(String value){
        return (value == null || (value != null && value.isEmpty()));
    }`
and now in app code I don't need to worry about the construct anymore:
`if(Helper.IsNullOrEmpty(mystring)) { // do something }`

Comment: @TonyG you don't need the `value != null` because java `if`s are lazy: if it gets to that point, it's already not null and you're safe to run `.isEmpty()` on the value.

Comment: awesome explanation..! :)

Answer (score 3):

Strings that have assigned with "", don't contain any value but are empty (length=0), Strings that are not instantiated are null.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `name` isn't a String. It's a *reference* to a String.

Hence the null check determines if `name` actually *references* a `String`. If it does, then (and only then) can you perform a further check to see if it's empty. i.e.

```
String name = null;  // no string
String name = "";    // an 'empty' string
```

are two different cases. Note that if you don't check for nullness first, then you'll try and call a method on a null reference and that's when you get the dreaded `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

`isEmpty()` checks for empty string `""`,

it will throw `NullPointerException` if you invoke `isEmpty()` on `null` instance

Answer (score 0):

If you apply this code:

```
if(name.isEmpty())
{
    //do something
}
```

when `name` is null, you'll get `NullPointerException`.

`null` checking shows you whether there is an object generally.
`isEmpty` checking shows you whether the content of **existing** `String` object is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Look at source code of your java version.

For example, in openjdk-7: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html

```
  119       /** The count is the number of characters in the String. */
  120       private final int count;

  663       /**
  664        * Returns <tt>true</tt> if, and only if, {@link #length()} is <tt>0</tt>.
  665        *
  666        * @return <tt>true</tt> if {@link #length()} is <tt>0</tt>, otherwise
  667        * <tt>false</tt>
  668        *
  669        * @since 1.6
  670        */
  671       public boolean isEmpty() {
  672           return count == 0;
  673       }
```

Answer (score 0):

isEmpty checks for String "".
Best practise is to check:

```
if (str != null && !str.isEmpty() {
   // process string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue this week while modifying some old JaVa code and i learn here that i must always make all those check. The answer is indeed correct but i find it hard to remember each time so i decide to make a little function that do it  for me in 1 simple call.

whit this, you always get the answer you want :

```
      public boolean StringIsNull(String pi_sChaine)
        {  boolean bTrueOrFalse = true;

           if (pi_sChaine == null || pi_sChaine.isEmpty())
             { bTrueOrFalse = true; }
           else
             { bTrueOrFalse = false; }

           return bTrueOrFalse;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to add an explanation to your code. This question is almost *seven years old*, and already has an accepted answer. Adding an explanation will bring your answer closer to the quality of the others', and make yours less likely to be removed.

Comment: Great! Please add your explanation *directly in the question*, **not** as a comment underneath it